# Existing maintenance plan backup causing 3rd party SQL backup to fail

Tags: sql-server, backup, maintenance

I have a problem with SQL Server backup on the MS SQL Server 2008R2 (SP1) 10.50.2500.

Basically there is a maintenance plan backing up SQL databases into the `physical_device_id` which is showing up as a string of numbers similar to `UUID ({761607B3-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}11})`, the software_vendor_id = 4608 and the `user_name = NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`.

When trying to access the existing maintenance plan:

```
use msdb

select * from sysmaintplan_sublpans
select * from sysmaintplan_plans
```

I have no output.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The database server is being backed up by a third party tool not the maintenance plans. 
The following query will show you the backup vendor information

```
select 
 software_vendor_id
 ,name
 ,description
 ,user_name
from msdb.dbo.backupset
```

Comment: Thanks Sporri as the software_vendor_id is 4608 it is the maintenance plan? (please correct me if I'm wrong). The name and description fields are NULL,

Comment: The software_vendor_id is I think always 4608, Then the backup process is not registering itself.  check select * from msdb.dbo.backupset and you will see the path to where the backups are made, that could help